# javax addToSNIServerNameList(): avoid server replacement in SNI

Tags: java, ssl, sni

I use a HTTPS Connection on my CLient in multiple Threads. Sometimes up to 20 times / second.
I have made the following observation: somethimes the HTTPS Connection is reconnected with TLS Handshake and this debug message appears:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|42|Thread-15|2022-12-02 13:48:47.748 CET|Utilities.java:73|the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=myServer.com) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=myServer.com)
```

After this message the TLS Handshake is made again.

**How can I avoid the reconnection and the server replacment in the SNI?**

In every thread this code is executed:

```
public SOAPConnecti2n soapConnection
soapConnection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection(); // done 1x in every thread in the constructor of the class

SOAPMessage response = soapConnection.call(myRequest, myURLEndpoint) // done x times in ervery thread in a for loop
```

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpsClient#afterConnect` calls `SSLSocketImpl#setHost` which replaces the first `SNIHostName` (more precisely the `SNIServerName` with type 0 - as the [RFC6066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-3) defines just type 0) with the hostname from the HTTPS Connection. So the trick is not to use the **hostname** for the connection, but to use the **IP address** instead for the connection. That way, the `Utilities` won't find the hostname to replace the SNIHostNames in the SSLParameters.